# When clustering with OpenRefine, is there a way to "exclude" a string in a cluster ? right now it feels like either it clusterize everything or not

Tags: openrefine

When using the clustering function in OpenRefine, you can select the "Merge?" option to clusterize the strings that were put together with the method of your choose, but what if the method clusterizes correctly most of them except for one string that I manually identify doesnt belongs in th ecluster, is there a way to exclude that specific string from the rest of the cluster ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not currently a way of excluding or selecting a subset of terms from a cluster. The only two options I can think of are:

- a) modify the clustering algorithm you are using to try to get better
  clustering which doesn't include the incorrect terms
- b) Go to 'browse
  cluster' and mark the rows with the terms you don't want to have in
  the cluster (e.g. by Flagging the rows), exclude the flagged rows in
  a facet and re-cluster - this will then not include any of the terms
  you didn't want

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for the answer, so if i exclude them from the facet, they will still appear in the original database with their correspondant string, right ?

Comment: @JuanLopez This is a known limitation and the enhancement request is tracked in our Issue https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1009

Feel free to post your additional comments or needs in that issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Thad thanks for anwering, I see this comes since 2015 so I assume the probability of this being adressed soon is low, do you think that Owen's method is the best way to overcome this ? as I asked Owen, if I exclude those strings from the facet, they will still appear in the original database with their correspondant string, right ?

Comment: Wrong.  Facets always affect further operations in OpenRefine.  That is one of the benefits of Facets!  Using Facets allows you to filter out noise and unwanted rows of cells that you do not want to process/clean/transform.

Comment: Hi Juan - I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question. If you exclude cells from your clustering, then the strings in those cells would no longer appear in your cluster, and so you wouldn't be making any changes to those. Is that what you were asking?